# Adding a root CA certificate to the iPhone's trust store programmatically

Tags: iphone, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am told it's possible to add root CA certificates to the iPhone using Safari, by putting the cert on a web server and loading up the URL in Safari.

Is it also possible to silently install a root CA cert from within an iPhone app? If so, how?

Comment: Being able to silently install a root cert sounds like a security flaw to me...

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in a way that, every iPhone have it own keychain. You can install it there. Then you have to write your own code to verify the certficate. Cannot be used as root CA of other apps.
you can see the, 
`NSURLProtectionSpace` class reference.
Core functions like, `SecIdentity, SecIdentityVerify, SecIdentityAdd` etc...